# How do I import a library so I can use it in a TypeScript file?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 6 app. I'm trying to use TypeScript. I've used Nuget to pull in the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild library. I've added a tsconfig.json file to the root of my project. I am targeting modern browsers in my environment and so ES6 should be fine for the output js files.

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Classic",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ],
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
 },
 "include": [
   "scripts/**/*"
 ]
}
```

This is my index.cshtml view:

```
@model GroupingForm

@section Scripts {
    <partial src="~/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial"></partial>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="~/js/index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
<table id="example-table"></table>
```

Here's my ts file:

```
import { Tabulator } from '../wwwroot/lib/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js';
```

Bizarrely, the browser gives me a 404 for loading the tabulator.min.js file.

Comment: 404 for loading the tabulator.min.js 
so is this file there?
'../wwwroot/lib/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js'

Comment: Yes, and visual studio validates it. If I change it, visual studio underlines as 'cannot find...'

Comment: I'm not using any kind of 'loader'. I am just trying to import in Tabulator so I can configure it for use in the page that this js file is referenced by.

Comment: Hmmm. You sure this should have a relative path like this? '../wwwroot/lib' once deployed? Like maybe that's where it is in the SOLUTION but once it's built and running somewhere, is that structure the same?

Comment: There's some disconnect between what the compiler wants and what the browser wants.

Comment: The browser doesn't know typescript. What are you using the generate the javascript? Babel, webpack, something else?

Comment: I agree with you -- the wwwroot should not be there but the stupid compiler demands it or else I cannot run the app. Clearly this software was not designed with ASP.NET Core MVC developers in mind. It's incredibly confusing.

Comment: Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild is what generates the JavaScript.

Comment: Is this a 3rd party script you're trying to use? I found this and you need npm for that I think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-aspnet-with-typescript?view=vs-2022

Comment: Yes. I want to import Tabulator.

Comment: I've chased endless permutations of tsconfig values for target, module, moduleResolution, etc.